# Delete worksheet from excel workbook using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

Below is the code I have which is creating graph and saving the graph as image

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application

$outputXLSX = "C:\report_10_02.xlsx"
$data = Import-Excel -Path $outputXLSX

$cd = New-ExcelChartDefinition -XRange Name -YRange Count -ChartType ColumnStacked3D -Height 300 -Title "Latency Count" -Width 1000 -SeriesHeader Count
$data | Export-Excel $outputXLSX -ExcelChartDefinition $cd -AutoNameRange -WorksheetName "Sheet2" 
$macros_wb = $excel.Workbooks.open($outputXLSX)

$chart_worksheets = @("Sheet2")

$OutputType = "JPG"

foreach ($item in $chart_worksheets)
    {
        $macros_ws = $macros_wb.WorkSheets.item($item)
        $macros_ws.activate()
        $excelchart = $macros_ws.ChartObjects(1)
        $Excel.Goto($excelchart.TopLeftCell,$true) 
        $ImagePath = "C:\Imagee.jpg"
        if ($excelchart.Chart.Export($ImagePath, $OutputType)) #Export returns true/false for success/failure
            {Write-Output "Exported $ImagePath"}
        else
            {Write-Output "Failure Exporting $ImagePath"}
    }


$WorkSheet = $macros_wb.sheets.item($chart_worksheets)
#Deleting the worksheet
$WorkSheet.Delete()
#Saving the worksheet
$macros_wb.Save()
$macros_wb.close($true)
$excel.Quit()
```

The excel workbook is having 2 worksheet in which I want to delete **Sheet2**. I tried **Delete()** but it is not deleting the sheet.

Please let me know what is wrong here

Comment: You have defined `$charts_worksheets` as array using `@()`, which cause `$WorkSheet = $macros_wb.sheets.item($chart_worksheets)` not to get the sheet. `$macros_wb.sheets.item("Sheet2").Delete()` should work. Also `$macros_wb.sheets.item($chart_worksheets[0]).Delete()` should do the trick.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks for the response. I tried your both approach, but still it is not deleting the Sheet. It is not giving any error also.

Comment: Your code is not showing where you define `$excel` and it is advisable to set `$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false` if you don't want any user confirmation box when deleting a worksheet. The `Delete()` method should return either $true or $false. Can you test if you indeed get a WorkSheet object when using `$WorkSheet = $macros_wb.sheets.item("Sheet2")` ?

Comment: `$macros_wb.sheets.item($chart_worksheets[0])` this is returning Sheet2 object. and `$excel` is `$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application` added in code

Comment: Are you running this multiple times? Then don't forget to add this at the end: `$excel.Quit(); $null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($worksheet);
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($macros_wb); 
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel); 
[System.GC]::Collect(); 
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()` to remove the COM objects from memory. Otherwise previous Excel instances may keep the file open (and eventually you will run out of system resources)

Comment: @Theo: Not running multiple times. alredy kept `$excel.Quit()` in the code

Comment: Just `$excel.Quit()` is not enough.. You need to remove the used COM objects with the code I gave in my previous comment.

Comment: @Theo: added them also. getting error like `Exception calling "ReleaseComObject" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

Comment: There you go then. At least one of your variables is not a com object... Check the naming of the variables, perhaps somewhere there is a typo

Comment: @Theo: Thanks a ton for your help..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you have an Excel file containing a chart you want to export to a JPG file and afterwards delete the worksheet containing that chart.

Using COM objects you can do this like so:

```
$outputXLSX      = "C:\report_10_02.xlsx"
$chart_worksheet = "Sheet2"
$ImagePath       = "C:\Imagee.jpg"
$OutputType      = "JPG"

$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$macros_wb = $excel.Workbooks.open($outputXLSX)
$macros_ws = $macros_wb.WorkSheets.item($chart_worksheet)
$macros_ws.activate()
$excelchart = $macros_ws.ChartObjects(1)
$excel.Goto($excelchart.TopLeftCell,$true) 
if ($excelchart.Chart.Export($ImagePath, $OutputType)) {Write-Host "Exported $ImagePath"}
else {Write-Warning "Failure Exporting $ImagePath"}

$macros_ws.Delete()
#Saving the worksheet
$macros_wb.Save()
$macros_wb.Close($true)

$excel.Quit()
# important, remove the used COM objects from memory
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($macros_ws)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($macros_wb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why are you using `ComObject` if you already have the ImportExcel Module installed, it doesn't require manipulation with `ComObject`. Here is how you can remove a Worksheet from an Excel file:

```
$path = 'path/to/excelfile.xlsx'
$workSheetToRemove = 'worksheetName'
Remove-Worksheet -WorksheetName $workSheetToRemove -FullName $path
```

If you're not sure what's the name of the Worksheet you want to remove, you use:

```
Get-ExcelFileSummary $path
```

Comment: I remove all the excel COM related codes and it worked fine. but it gave me another problem. the excel piece of code was saving the graph as image which I have to send as email body. now what to do with that part?